# How to change the size limit of a quick launch subfolders

Tags: sharepoint-addin, quick-launch, subfolders

I have created a folder on my quick launch but now it only shows 5 items as subfolders even though I have 7 subfolders.How do I incease the size limit of quick launch folder?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Check the configuration here:  
/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses,I have managed to get an answer,I went to site settings-->Navigation-->Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting in that list the folders will be listed I added a new one and removed the subfolders to the newly created one.